The NuGet-based SDK resolver failed to run because NuGet assemblies could not be located
32-bit Visual Studio (up to and including 2019) refuses to load SDK-style projects.  When user hits reload, this warning shows up.
warning MSB4243: The NuGet-based SDK resolver failed to run because NuGet assemblies could not be located.  Check your installation of MSBuild or set the environment variable "MSBUILD_NUGET_PATH" to the folder that contains the required NuGet assemblies. Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\<some.kinda.version>\microsoft.net.sdk.android\WorkloadManifest.json'.

How to get back to good?

In the environment path, ensure the 32-bit dotnet path is mentioned before the 64-bit one.
See https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/5962#issuecomment-780084535 for details.
